# Why does the Persian emissary display a string of crowned skulls?

Tags: 300

In *300*, when the Persian emissary arrives on horseback, he displays a string of crowned skulls, which are otherwise unexplained. What is the meaning of this?

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From what I remember, they are the skulls of Kings and Sovereigns that had refused to submit / 'offer Earth and Water' to Xerxes.

Leonidas:

> [...]
>
> No man, Persian or Greek,
>   no man threatens a messenger.
>
> You bring the crowns and heads
>   of conquered kings to my city steps.
>
> You insult my queen.
>
> [...]

[source](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/t/300-script-transcript-sparta.html)

Comment: @ThisClark Yes, that's why the question is specifically asking about *crowned* skulls.

Comment: [Video](https://youtu.be/J-rMbmCg6nc?t=127)